# F.A.U. and W.A. abbreviations on circuit breaker?

Tags: circuit-breaker, circuit

I think FAU means Forced Air Unit, but a different one says AC.  Why would there be both?

There are also two separate ones that say W.A.  What is that?

From top to bottom they say:

A.C. (two connected; each with number 40); 
DISH & DISP (two connected; each with number 20); 
WASH (20); 
F.A.U. (20); 
W.A. (20); 
MAIN (two connected; each with number 100); 
W.A. (20); 
PLUGS & LIGHTS (one label for next last 5, separate, labeled '15'); 
and two more, connected with no label each with number 50

Comment: Those numbers are amp ratings.  Most houses have a fuel-fired furnace that uses an electric air handler to push the warmed air through ducts into the house.  Of those houses, SOME have an air conditioning unit outside, and its chiller coils sits right above the furnace, so it uses the same air handler, now distributing chilled air instead of hot air.  The furnace is required to be on a dedicated breaker.  The A/C unit is way too big to share it anyway.

Comment: Furnace air handler must be on a dedicated breaker? I was thinking I could use the air handler circuit to power (the controls) for a gas fired tankless water heater if I would need to replace my current tankless water heater which is an early model without electronic controls.

Answer (score 1):

### FAU = Forced Air Unit (another name for an air handler)

A FAU is a Forced Air Unit, which is another name for an air handler, indoor unit, or AHU for short.  Whatever you call it, it consists of a blower, air conditioning coils, and sometimes electric heat strips or a hydronic coil, all wrapped up in a furnace-shaped package.  (It doesn't have a gas or oil burner in it, though, which is what distinguishes it from a furnace.)

The separate breaker labeled AC, then, turns off the outdoor (condensing) unit for your air conditioning or heat pump.  They are on separate breakers so that an issue with the air conditioning doesn't knock out the indoor unit and its air-circulating functions, or worse yet, your heat if you have a hydronic coil in your forced air unit.

### W.A. is likely your kitchen receptacle circuits

While I don't know what W.A. stands for precisely, from a process of elimination, we can deduce that those breakers likely feed your kitchen small appliance branch circuits, as the NEC requires at least two 20A circuits dedicated to the kitchen countertop receptacles.

Comment: WA = "Wet area" maybe?

Comment: @nobody -- perhaps, would be odd though

Answer (score -1):

If you have a outside compressor this requires a separate circuit than the air handler or forced air unit.  Wa to me would be water if you have a well. The double 50 is most often for an electric range.